# Mass-produce files named by date

Tags: file, rename, autohotkey, autoit

Using AutoHotkey or AutoIt I need to create (and name) a database (.db) file in the date format.

The files should be named `January/01/2000.db`, `January/02/2000.db`, etc. Right up to the present day; a new file for each day.

Additionally, the created files need to be in a new folder having the same name as the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**January/01/2000.db** is not a valid filename but a folder path!
The following AutoHotkey snippet would do it:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  
SetBatchLines -1

DatB := 20000101000000
DatE := SubStr( A_Now,1,8 ) . "000000"
While ( DatB <= DatE ) {
 FormatTime, DT, %DatB%, MMMM\dd
 FormatTime, YY, %DatB%, yyyy
 DatB += 1, Day
 FileCreateDir, %A_ScriptDir%\%DT%
 FileAppend,, %DT%\%YY%.db
}
```